# Closed form expressions for Perron-Frobenious left and right eigen vectors

Tags: matrices

Given any $n \times n$ matrix with all positive entries, is there any closed form expressions for Perron-Frobenious left and right eigenvectors ?

Comment: "Had it exist, it would be not known"... Up to my knowledge, no.

Comment: There is a semi-closed form expression. Just pick any nonzero column of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{A}{\rho(A)}\right)^n$.